# Use a NSOutputStream with AFURLSessionManager

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession, outputstream

AFNetworking was offering the `outputStream` property for `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. Right now I'm changing to `AFURLSessionManager` and I want to keep my logic but I don't know if it's possible.

Old logic (simplified):

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation*)doRequestWithOutputSteam:(NSOutputStream*) outputStream
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager* manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation = [manager GET:@"http://example.com/file/to/download"
                                   parameters:nil
                                      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                          NSLog(@"Success");
                                      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                      }];

    if (outputStream)
    {
        operation.outputStream = outputStream;
    }

    return operation;
}
```

I'm using this function because I'm streaming the data directly to another device. I don't want to wait until the download is finished and then stream the data to the device. I want to stream it while the data is received.

Question:
Is there a way to keep the behaviour while using `AFURLSessionManager` and `NSURLSession`?